# Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input

Tags: youtube-api, cocoapods, youtube-data-api

The contents from the Profile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'target 'u2apiv3test' do
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/YouTube', '~> 1.2.1'
pod 'Google/SignIn', '~> 3.0.3'
end
```

The errors:

```
 #  from /Volumes/Mac Data/Apple/Labs/u2apiv3test/Podfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  platform :ios, '8.0'target 'u2apiv3test' do
 #  pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/YouTube', '~> 1.2.1'
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I have updated cocoapods to the latest version.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new line after '8.0' missing.

It should look like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'u2apiv3test' do
  pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/YouTube', '~> 1.2.1'
  pod 'Google/SignIn', '~> 3.0.3'
end
```

**Demo**

When calling `pod install` it looks like this then:

[image: pod install call]

**Newer versions available**

The version numbers to be used depend, of course, on your requirements. Just wanted to mention it seems there are also newer versions available. You may want to consider using them:

```
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/YouTube', '~> 1.3'
```

There is also a newer version of the Google Sign-In SDK to allow users to sign in with their Google Account

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'
```